# Extra hidden resources created in arm template when creating web app resource in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template, azure-webapps

I'm currently working to setup an ARM-template for a resource group containing a web app for an API the I've been working on, i though it would be easier to first create the resource for the web app in the resource group an then export the template just to make sure i don't miss anything.

When exporting the template containing a test for the web app and the app service plan i noticed a bunch of extra resources that seem to be hidden in the background:

(Red overlines are deleted, related to application insights, yellow highlighter are the ones I'm asking about)

[image]

Are these needed for initial deployment of the web app and ASP, or can these be removed? I'm trying to keep the template as "clean" as possible, if one can say that. :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test this in our local environment, we have deployed an webapp from portal & enabled application insights to it .

While exporting the template of the webapp & associated application insights we can also see additional resources like (Host name Bindings, Basic publishing credentials policies (ftp,scm),smart alerts etc.,) are in the template.

We have removed all those **HostNameBindings,BasicPublishingCredentialPolicies (ftp,scm)** properties  from the exported template & tried deploying a new web app  it got successfully deployed without any issues.

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the only resources i need in practice are the templates and parameters for the ASP and the Web App?

Comment: Based on my understanding , yes you require template & parameter of ASP & Web app & You can refer this git hub for more sample templates of web apps https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web

Comment: While we are at the subject, did you need to specify the auto generated keys such as "customDomainVerificationId" to be able to deploy? it seems this one is unique for the resource template part related to the web app. What happens when you have different environments?

Comment: We have removed the "customDomainVerificationId" in the above template, we are able to deploy the webapp successfully without any issues. Based on my understanding  customDomainVerificationId is a Unique identifier that verifies the custom domains assigned to the app. Customer will add this id to a txt record for verification.

Comment: Well this answer helped a lot, thanks, though i found another helpful thing that way be part of this answer in regards to whats necessary for a "slimmed down" template to be successful in deployment. Just before pushing the create button the resources you want in a resource group, there is a blue link to the right of the button in that last blade that says "Download a template for automation". That's basically all one needs to make a successful deployment.